# How to put array numbers into a dictionary in sequence in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here i tried the following code but not got required output i need to display the array as dictionary to get desired output as `["0.0": "50.0", "50.0": "100.0", "100.0": "150.0"]` which i am having is `[0.0, 50.0, 100.0, 150.0]` in `self.filteredPriceArr` can anyone help me how to implement this as required ?

```
       for (index,item) in self.filteredPriceArr.enumerated() {
            print(index)
            print(self.filteredPriceArr.count)
            if index + 1 != priceArray.count {
                priceDict.updateValue("\(self.filteredPriceArr[index + 1])", forKey: "\(self.filteredPriceArr[index])")
            }
            print(priceDict)
        }
```

Comment: Dictionary are not for ordering the data !! it will always in alphabetical order

Comment: could n't understand what ur saying  @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: I mean you can't sort dictionary  if you are trying to do so, and what you are getting in output ?

Comment: ok understood @PrashantTukadiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put your code and there is one mistake  only

Which is `priceArray` should be  `filteredPriceArr`

```
var filteredPriceArr = [0.0, 50.0, 100.0, 150.0]

var priceDict:[String:String] = [:]

for (index,item) in filteredPriceArr.enumerated() {
    print(index)
    print(filteredPriceArr.count)
    if index + 1 != filteredPriceArr.count {
        priceDict.updateValue("\(filteredPriceArr[index + 1])", forKey: "\(filteredPriceArr[index])")
    }
}

print(priceDict)
```

here is output

> ["0.0": "50.0", "100.0": "150.0", "50.0": "100.0"]

You can't get it in following  ordered as you mentioned in question

**["0.0": "50.0", "50.0": "100.0", "100.0": "150.0"]**

Dictionary can not be sorted !!